# Embed another project in current project

Tags: android

I have 2 projects, and I want to embed a project in other. I have created 2 projects and have made a project as library file and inserted in other but I am still unable to get it working. I have taken a simple activity and want to display a toast message, using Intent I have given the address of the next project library. This is the code of the main (first) project.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.sec_pro";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.sec_pro.MainActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.integrate.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.sec_pro.MainActivity" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Now this "sec_pro" is the library file of my next project which I have inserted in the first project.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste your manifest file.

Comment: Is com.example.sec_pro.MainActivity in your library project? Have you added com.example.sec_pro.MainActivity activity tag to your main project's manifest?

Comment: I made the changes and edited the question. But now I have an image in the sec_pro lib file and it is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed to declare your library activity in Manifest.

try this code to declare in to manifest under application tag:

```
<activity android:name="PackageName.YourLibraryActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check `onClick` method again, I think you missed a statement:

```
startActivity(intent);
```